# Deploy Angular and Web API in different solutions to Azure?

Tags: angular, azure

we are extremely new to Azure App Service and need help with deploying a **window-based web application** to Azure Portal.  The web application consists of the following:

1. An Angular 9 SPA UI in a project of its own solution
2. A Web API .NET EF Core 3.1 in a project of its own solution
3. A SQL Database as storage

All of these solutions are under the Azure DevOps repo.

As of today, we deploy our application to IIS Server on Prem using Azure DevOps Build/Release pipelines.  We have 2 distinct pipelines.  One for deploying the Angular UI and the other for deploying the Web API.

**Problem:**

We want to migrate our application to Azure Portal.  The data center created a single App Service container for **Web App on Linux**, but we do not know how to set up the configurations so that we can deploy the API and the UI in 2 separate deployments.  In other words, we want to replicate our existing processes.  Since all of us are new to Azure, we would like to know if anybody has some suggestions on how to make this work?  We do not care if we have to do in a single deployment or multiple deployments.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of common approaches here:

1. Deploy your web API to the app service and [deploy your angular app to an azure storage account in a blob container](https://johnpapa.net/deploy-angular-to-azure-vsts-angular-cli/). You can then expose your blob container via [a custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal) or you could use [a function proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#a-namemodify-requestsamodifying-backend-requests) to do the same thing (the latter can give you more control over routes and routing, eg if you wanted to serve static assets from somewhere else or transform routes.
2. Add a simple index endpoint to your API that serves your angular frontend, there are [helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.spaapplicationbuilderextensions.usespa?view=aspnetcore-3.0) within the framework for this.

I’d suggest looking at option 1 as it’s a better fit for what you’ve described, ie you have two deployment pipelines already and a “pure” API not an MVC app.

I’m assuming you’ve already created/deployed your SQL database to azure SQL.

Comment: @user:934407 (Matt), thank you for responding.  At this point, we only have a single App Service.  We do not have Azure Storage or SQL Database created on the Azure Portal.  Our existing build pipeline for the Web API  using Redgate as one of the tasks to deploy the SQL database.

I will take your advice back to our data center team who is currently working with us on setting up the configurations. If this works, I will mark the post as "answered".

Comment: Thanks Alex, you have a few SQL options on Azure which you may need to look at as well in that case. Simplest is to use Azure SQL database which is a fully managed HA and backed up service work a bunch of price/performance options. Hosting yourself in a VM is also an option but more complex to set up.

Comment: @user:934407 (Matt), my data center managed to get the Web API deployed successfully to the Azure Portal.  For the Angular, we are still working on it.  I have one question.  We zipped up our static files during the build process and place the zip file into a drop zone.  Do we have to include a step where we need to extract the files on the Azure Portal?

Comment: @AlexL - [here's a blog post](http://www.frankysnotes.com/2019/03/deploy-automatically-static-website.html) describing how you can use Azure DevOps to copy files to Azure storage - when I've done this I've also used a function proxy as described in my answer so the CLI step to enable static sites wasn't necessary - I'm not sure if it still is necessary if you're using a custom domain only. HTH

Comment: @user:934407 (Matt), we finally got our build/release pipeline to work using YAML.  We can build and release successfully.  Pass the first hurdle.  Our hurdle #2 is trying to get our Swagger page to work on Azure Portal.  The Swagger page works correctly on IIS server but for Azure, the controllers are not hit at all.  We know it has to do with the routes and currently working on it.